# Flutter expand Stack size after rotation

Tags: flutter, dart

**What I do :**

I want to rotate my yellow balls so that the selected ball is always on the right (at the location of the zero ball).
My code works here is what it gives :

[image]

---

**My problem :**

As you can see on my video, when I click on a yellow ball, depending on its position, I rotate all the balls. For this I directly turn the `Stack` in pink. The problem is that when I rotate the stack 90 degrees, the width is the old height. I would like the stack to adapt to all the screen.
We can see that when I click on my `ball 1` outside the stack, the click is no longer taken into account...

***How to do that ??***

---

**My code:**

```
class NodeV2View extends StatefulWidget {
  const NodeV2View({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NodeV2View> createState() => _NodeV2ViewState();
}

class _NodeV2ViewState extends State<NodeV2View> {
  bool isExpand = false;
  int? selectedChildrenIndex;

  void changeSelectedChildrenIndex(int i){
    setState(() {
      if(selectedChildrenIndex == null){
        selectedChildrenIndex = i;
      }else{
        selectedChildrenIndex = null;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var controller = Provider.of<CompteurProvider2>(context);

    return Scaffold(
        body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints){
            return SizedBox(
              height: constraints.maxHeight,
              width: constraints.maxWidth,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => setState(() {}),
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: [
                    AnimatedContainer(
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                      height: isExpand == true ? constraints.maxHeight : constraints.maxHeight - controller.nodeChildrenSize - 10,
                      width: isExpand == true ? constraints.maxWidth : constraints.maxWidth - controller.nodeChildrenSize - 10,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 3, color: isExpand == true ? Colors.transparent : Colors.red),
                          shape: BoxShape.circle
                      ),
                    ),
                   AnimatedRotation(
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                      turns: isExpand == true
                          ? ((controller.convertRadiantToDegree(controller.betweenAngle) * selectedChildrenIndex!) >= 180)
                            ? 360 - (controller.convertRadiantToDegree(controller.betweenAngle) * selectedChildrenIndex!) / 360
                            : - controller.convertRadiantToDegree(controller.betweenAngle) * selectedChildrenIndex! / 360
                          : 0,
                     child: children(constraints),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        )
    );
  }

  Widget children(BoxConstraints constraints)
  {
    final children = <Widget>[];
    var controller = Provider.of<CompteurProvider2>(context);
    
    for(var i = 0; i < controller.tree.children!.length; i++)
      children.add(
          AnimatedPositioned(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            top: isExpand == true
                ? constraints.maxHeight / 2 - controller.nodeChildrenSize / 2 + controller.calc(i, constraints.maxHeight / 2).dy
                : constraints.maxHeight / 2 - controller.nodeChildrenSize / 2 + controller.calc(i, (constraints.maxHeight - controller.nodeChildrenSize - 10) / 2).dy,
            left: isExpand == true
                ?  constraints.maxWidth / 2 - controller.nodeChildrenSize / 2 + controller.calc(i, constraints.maxHeight / 2).dx
                : constraints.maxWidth / 2 - controller.nodeChildrenSize / 2 + controller.calc(i, (constraints.maxHeight - controller.nodeChildrenSize - 10) / 2).dx,
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              //clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  child: AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                    height: isExpand == true ? controller.nodeSize : controller.nodeChildrenSize,
                    width: isExpand == true ? controller.nodeSize : controller.nodeChildrenSize,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: selectedChildrenIndex == i || selectedChildrenIndex == null ? Colors.yellow : Colors.yellow,
                        shape: BoxShape.circle
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: (){
                    setState(() {
                      isExpand = !isExpand;
                      changeSelectedChildrenIndex(i);
                    });
                  },
                ),
                AnimatedRotation(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                    turns: isExpand == true
                      ? ((controller.convertRadiantToDegree(controller.betweenAngle) * selectedChildrenIndex!) >= 180)
                        ? 360 + (controller.convertRadiantToDegree(controller.betweenAngle) * selectedChildrenIndex!) / 360
                        : controller.convertRadiantToDegree(controller.betweenAngle) * selectedChildrenIndex! / 360
                      : 0,
                    child: Visibility(
                      visible: selectedChildrenIndex == i || selectedChildrenIndex == null ? true : true,
                      child: Text(
                        i.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    )
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
      );
    
    return Container(
      color: Colors.pink,
      height: constraints.maxWidth,
      width: constraints.maxWidth,
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: children,
      ),
    );
      
  }
}
```

**Any guidance on the best way to accomplish this would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Use MediaQuery

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StackRotateExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const StackRotateExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StackRotateExample> createState() => _StackRotateExampleState();
}

class _StackRotateExampleState extends State<StackRotateExample> {
  bool isRotate = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => setState(() {
          isRotate = !isRotate;
        }),
        child: RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: isRotate == false ? 0 : 1,
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            height: isRotate == false ? size.height : size.width,
            width: isRotate == false ? size.width : size.height,
            color: Colors.teal,
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: const [
                Text("TEXT"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```